# <video> src to follow url to source

Tags: html

If I have a `<video>` element that looks like this:

```
<video autoplay="" controls="" width="300" src="/users/1/videos/29"></video>
```

And going to `/users/1/videos/29` returns this:

```
http://localhost:5100/rails/active_storage/disk/wrestle.mov
```

Why won't the video be recognised in the HTML element?

[image]

Comment: I think it's the problem with the video format try using mp4 or webm or ogg
 <source src="/users/1/videos/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: But the URL returns the JSON of the source... would that really do it?

Comment: You can parse the JSON

Comment: There's no file extension for my URL, the extension is only if you follow the redirect

Comment: What do you mean by `/users/1/videos/29` returns `http://localhost:5100/rails/active_storage/disk/wrestle.mov` ? is it returning the path or returning a stream of video data?

Comment: What is the logic behind `/users/1/videos/29`? Is it returning the stream or only path?

Comment: It's returning the path—I need a temp. URL generated server-side, and going to `/users/1/videos/29` generates one.

Comment: What language you are using?

Comment: Front end or backend? I'm in JS/Vue for this component, the back is Rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this with a JS function, it's not *ideal* but at least the Activestorage stuff in Rails standardised.

```
function loadVideos() {
  var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video')

  for (var video of videos) {
    if (!video.src.includes('.')) {
      fetch(video.src)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
           console.log(`json: ${JSON.stringify(json.video)}`)
           video.src = json.video
        })
    }
  }
}
```